# How can i assign to a variable, response from the WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, options)?

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst

can i assign the result from the WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, options) to a variable.

```
function getCategory(){

        var invocationData = {
            adapter : 'Go2needsSQL',
            procedure : 'myLatLang',
            parameters : []
        };
        var options = {
            onSuccess : procedureSuccess,
            onFailure : procedureFailure,
            invocationContext: {}
        };

        var r = WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, options);
        alert(JSON.stringify(r));
        }

        function procedureSuccess(result){

            return result;

            } 

        function procedureFailure(){
            alert("Failed");
        }
```

In above code the alert() is giving null json response.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can but according to the [docs](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_5.0.5/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_client_invokeprocedure.html), it returns nothing (`undefined`)
the result is obtained asynchronously, so when you `alert` there is no result as the function returns `undefined`.

You have to use the success handler which is called later when the procedure has been invoked:

```
function getCategory() {
    var result;
    var invocationData = {
        adapter: 'Go2needsSQL',
        procedure: 'myLatLang',
        parameters: []
    };
    var options = {
        onSuccess: procedureSuccess,
        onFailure: procedureFailure,
        invocationContext: {}
    };

    result = WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, options);

    alert(JSON.stringify(result)); ///this will alert nothing
}

function procedureSuccess(__result) {
    result = __result;
    alert(JSON.stringify(result)) //this will be okay
}

function procedureFailure() {
    alert("Failed");
}
```